# Is homogeneous soln. same as particular soln. when the RHS is 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know this is probably pretty dumb a for DE student to be asking. But, My problem requires me to use either the Variation of Parameters Method or the Undetermined Coefficients Method to solve some DEs, however, in the problem, the right-hand side(or RHS) is =0. does this mean that the homogeneous solution is the particular solution?

Comment: Post the equation thats better. $y''+2y'+y+2x=0$ has RHS equal zero but it's still an inhomogeneous equation. RHS=0 means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. When you are solving some *inhomogeneous* linear equation, your solution would be the homogeneous solution plus the particular solution.

When the DE is *homogeneous*, you can pick the particular solution to be the zero function, so the homogeneous solution becomes the total solution to your equation.